# How to save User objects in many to many field?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'd like to save two user objects in a `ManyToManyField` after a form `POST`, like so :

```
ManytoManyField: [<User: user1>, <User: user2>]
```

here is the error I get when I try to save the m2m field :

> ValueError: "..." needs to have a value for field "message" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.

Here is what my code looks like, templates/**page.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="...to my view...">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name='message'>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    user1 = ...<User: user1>...
    user2 = ...<User: user2>...
    two_users = user1, user2

    form = MessageForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        for u in two_users
            save_it.users.add(u)
        save_it.save()
        return redirect('/')
    ...

return render(request, "room.html", {...})
```

**models.py :**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    message = models.CharField(...)
    ...
```

This code is an example of what I'm trying to do, this is what it should look like in the admin page after being saved :

[image]

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `MessageForm` is a `ModelForm`, you have to access its `.instance` attribute:

```
save_it.instance.users.add(u)
```

(instead of `save_it.users.add(u)` in your code above.)

You will also need to `.save()` without `commit=False` before this line in order to allow using many-to-many relationships.

Comment: I still get the same error message `needs to have a value for field "message" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`